# Drupal Commerce Paypal WPS

Tags: 7, commerce, payment-gateways

I have a Drupal 7 site running the latest Drupal Commerce and Paypal WPS as a payment method.  Everything is working correctly.  When a customer is checking out and can pick between Paypal and credit card, the radio button for the area that lists the credit card does not show up.

Screen shot attached.
[image]

I've checked and re-checked every possible setting.  Is there a way to disable the Paypal only button and enable the credit card and paypal option?  Or just get the radio button to show up so users can pick.

I've inspected elements and the input tag is not present in the html.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PayPal WPS submodule of [Commerce PayPal](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_paypal) provides only one payment option, which redirects the user to PayPal for payment. Credit card icons are there to let users know that at PayPal's end they will be able to make the payment via PayPal balance or using listed credit cards.

You see only one radio button for PayPal WPS payment method because it is expected behavior. If you wish to allow your users to pay via credit card without leaving your website - enable PayPal WPP submodule.

Comment: Thank you!  I was hoping it was normal behavior and that I wasn't missing something.